# How to add an object to a list inside a session in c#

Tags: c#, session, authentication

What i'm trying to do is something like this (but this code, obviusly doesn't work):

```
lstEstudiantes = new List<Estudiante.Estudiante>();
Estudiante.Estudiante estNuevo = new Estudiante.Estudiante();

Session["listado"] = lstEstudiantes;
Session["listado"].Add(estNuevo);
```

Any ideas how to archieve this?, this is in C# btw.

Answer (score 1):

```
((Estudiante.Estudiante)Session["listado"]).Add(estNuevo);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that `Session[...]` returns an `object` which doesn't have an `Add` method, if you want to use it you have to *cast* it, like this (assuming `lstEstudiante` is a `List<Estudiante.Estudiante>`):

```
((List<Estudiante.Estudiante>)Session["listado"]).Add(estNuevo);
```

you should also consider using some variable to store the list if you're planning on making several operation with it (like calling `Add` several times)